# Linux: Recreate parent directories when moving files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory, mv

in my working directory I have several folders which have hundreds of files of different types (.txt, .csv, .png...). These folders are structured as this example:

```
myDir/
myDir/Folder_1/ ... file_1.txt, file_2.csv, file_3.txt
myDir/Folder_2/ ...
myDir/Folder_3/ ...
...
```

I need to move all the .csv files to a new directory but keeping the same directory tree like this:

```
myDir/
myDir/Folder_1/ ...
myDir/Folder_2/ ...
...
myDir/New/
myDir/New/Folder_1/ ... file_2.csv
myDir/New/Folder_2/ ...
...
```

I found that cp command has `--parents` flag that does what I want to do, but I don't want to copy these files, I only want to move them.

I searched for this question before and found this one: [Bash script for moving files and their parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272825)

It is quite similar to what I need to do, but I'm not able to understand it.

Comment: Then copy **and** delete them?

Comment: I cannot copy those files due to two reasons: disk space and execution time. That's why I was trying to move them. As far I know, moving files between 2 directories in the same disk (with same file system) is an instant action that does not requires to create a copy

Comment: @MiguelHerreraRuiz, you may need `rsync` for this. it has capability of moving(without copying) to another directory. Also it is much intelligent command than cp/scp etc, even it gets cancelled in between(or stopped/killed by any way) when you run rsync command(which you used very first time) it will start moving/copying files from the end of last run, because it handles things on storage block level. Its not default utility of bash so you may need to install it in case its not installed in your system.

Comment: OK I'll try to move them using rsync

Comment: @MiguelHerreraRuiz, be careful and test it for a single test or so directory before running them to actual ones.

Comment: Yes, I have a little test directory with the same structure. I only found the `--remove-source-files` flag for this, but it copies all the files and removes them one by one. I haven't found which flag should be the most appropriate for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the commands the following snippet prints out. If they do what you want, then just remove the `echo` (before `mkdir` and `mv`).

```sh
for path in myDir/*; do
  [[ -d "$path" ]] && echo mkdir -p "myDir/New/${path#myDir/}"
done

for csv in myDir/*/*.csv; do
  echo mv "$csv" "myDir/New/${csv#myDir/}"
done
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks!! I thought that this task could be solved using an one-line bash command.

Comment: It could be made more efficient by callng `mv` once per directory instead of once per file. As for the one-liner, you can type it that way, but the question is whether something with semicolons still counts as a one-liner. 